# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined while running detox test command

Tags: detox

I am trying to run the detox test using the package.json confugation

```
detox test --configuration -l verbose android.emu.release
```

got this error

```
(config.configurations[program.configuration].type).split('.')[0]; ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

script under package.json

`"script":{
"e2e:test-release": "detox test --configuration android.device.release.debug"
}`

configuration in package.json

`"android.emu.releaseTest":{
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
        "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Nexus_5X_API_27"
      }`

Answer (score 0):

doing a mistake in the command while passing the `-l verbose` option

`detox test --configuration -l verbose android.emu.release`

changed that to

`detox test --confituration android.emu.release -l verbose`